# Javascript appendChild doesn't append element and no errors in console

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to create a 16X16 square grid using javascript. When I've tried to trouble shoot this using dev tools - there are no errors in the console but the `div`'s I'm trying to append are missing. Here's the relevant code snippets:

```js
window.addEventListener("onload", function () {

  var square = document.createElement("div")
  square.className = "square"
  var grid = document.getElementById("grid")

  var make_grid = function(){
    var line = 0;
    while (line < 16){
      for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        grid.appendChild(square)
      }
      line ++;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="grid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe I've been looking at this too long, but I can't figure out the flaw(s) in my code/logic.

I should also point out that I know the squares aren't going to appear next to each other in a nice grid right now - I haven't added the proper css for that yet. I'd like to tackle that issue after I get SOMETHING at least appearing on my screen.

Comment: Sure its running? "load" not "onload"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two problems here.

1. You're never calling your make_grid function
2. You're appending the same element multiple times. You need to create a new one each time or it's just going to move the existing one.

And a third one:

3. The event name you want to listen for is `load` not `onload`

Comment: missing another issue with onload

Comment: Thank you! This really helped. I'm feeling a bit stupid about forgetting to call make_grid(); - I'll work on point #2 now and I'll accept your answer as soon as SO let's me!

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually calling the function, all you've done is simply declare it. Add:

```
make_grid();
```

To the end of your function to invoke the function.